# JSF2.2 faces flow method call node

Tags: jsf-2.2, faces-flow

I am currently using JSF 2.2 faces flow with WildFly8.2.0 as JAVA EE 7 server.

Can anyone has any idea of , how to use/configure method call node using XML file configuration ? 
I know how to invoke it using FlowBuilder API , but haven't found any tutorial on how to use XML for the same . (flowname-flow.xml).

Can anyone please help ?

Comment: Is your question specifically looking for the tutorial, or is your question how to use the method call node in the XML syntax? Finding a pre-written tutorial may be challenging, but there are likely users who already know the XML syntax and could directly answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the syntax for calling a method call node in FacesFlow -

```
 <flow-definition id="someFlow">
        <start-node>start</start-node>   
        <method-call id="start">
            <method>#{bean.init}</method>
            <default-outcome>success</default-outcome>
        </method-call>  
        <view id="initSuccess">
                <vdl-document>/pages/init.xhtml</vdl-document>    
        </view>                     
 </flow-definition>
```

where `#{bean.init}` returns outcome as `"initSuccess"` upon which `init.xhtml` is rendered.
success is the default outcome if method doesn't return anything.